# Attempt on Madagascar Penguins

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

I am trying to make a penguin from the movie penguins of madagascar. I managed to make the basic form and the eyes, but the problem is the beak.

[image]

I tried to make it from a cylinder but I looked awful, then I used a cone but same thing :(

Second problem is the "hair"(black parts of the penguin), how do you accomplish those round shapes?? I mean the round black part of the penguin's head? I ended up with a square black shape.

Comment: Can you post pictures of your work so far so we can get a better idea how to direct you? Thanks! -Ben

Comment: I'd recommend delving deeper into modeling in general. With better general modeling skills you'll learn how to solve these particular problems as well. CG cookie has some nice courses for all levels: https://cgcookie.com/flow/modeling-in-blender/

Comment: None of these shapes are super hard, so if you can't figure them out, try something easier.

Comment: Ask questions about each piece you are having trouble with separately, and more in depth.